# CopyOnWriteArrayList is not working as expected

Tags: multithreading, java-8, copyonwritearraylist

I am learning on CopyOnWriteArrayList and its not working as per my understanding.
I have two threads, one is main thread and another is inner thread. Main thread is removing the objects from the CopyOnWriteArrayList collection while inner thread is sleeping for 5 seconds. Main thread is completing the remove operations much before inner thread is iterating but inner thread is still iterating the full collection, I mean which are removed by main thread.

```
package com.kalavakuri.javaconcurrent;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class ConcurrentModificationExceptionExample {

    private static List<String> strings = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        strings.add("Ram");
        strings.add("Ravi");
        strings.add("Raju");
        strings.add("Raghu1");
        strings.add("Raghu2");
        strings.add("Raghu3");
        strings.add("Raghu4");
        strings.add("Raghu5");
        strings.add("Raghu6");

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            Iterator<String> iterator = strings.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
                System.out.println("Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, "Inner thread");

        thread.start();

        Iterator<String> iterator = strings.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String value = iterator.next();
            strings.remove(value);
            System.out.println("Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        strings.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v));

    }
}
```

I am expecting that inner thread should not iterate the objects which are removed by main thread. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html):

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of
>   the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never
>   changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is
>   impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

So by design the iterator will not change when the other thread makes changes.